# Feature for the [technical-issues] tag regarding games that crash

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-warning-request

After reading several questions such as [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46450/is-there-a-fix-for-random-crash-to-desktop), I wonder if we could add a popup message when a user is using the [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) tag. Something like this:

> If your game is crashing, make sure you have provided
>
> - Your hardware specification
> - The version of the drivers
> - The version of the game
> - Any [Windows Log](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

Those points would provide basic information regarding the issue, and most of the time these are the first questions that are asked in comments. I thought it could save some time for both the asker and the and the commenter if the information was provided directly in the question. Any thoughts?

Comment: There really isn't much point in having this kind of question anyway, random crashes are almost impossible for us to solve. The answer is almost always the same: Update all drivers, disable mods, don't overclock, check for overheating and so on. Even with the information you want to ask for we still can only offer wild guesses or general troubleshooting advice.

Comment: Popups are something that would have to be added by the SE developers, and I doubt it's worth their time for a relatively small tag (in the scope of SE as a whole). For [technical-issues], only 274 out of 633 (43%) which is low, but not much lower compared to other tags of a similar size ([borderlands-2]: 62%, [ps3]: 56%)

Comment: @fredley I understand, so maybe something in the FAQ/Help that answerer can refer to. Since those question are allowed, I feel like they should be written properly if not they'll end up closed for being too broad.

Comment: One thing you can do is formulate a comment that has some helpful information (emphasis on helpful, nice, etc, so it doesn't come off as standoffish or rude) and leave it where you see questions that could use help.  I've done this in the past and gotten good results.

Comment: [A later 2021 request for the same thing, in case someone is wondering whether this 2014 proposal still enjoys consensus](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15996/185203)

Answer (score 1):

Posting the wording suggested in [Tag Warnings: Looking for suggestions of tags that often got low quality questions and would benefit a warning when trying to add that tag](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15994/tag-warnings-looking-for-suggestions-of-tags-that-often-got-low-quality-questio/15996#15996) to keep things together:

> Make sure that if you have got an error message or code, google it before asking. If you can't find anything for it, make sure to include them in your question.

This seems to me like a better phrasing for a tag warning than the thing suggested in the question, which is overly specific and contains info that may not be applicable to every question.