# Tag Warnings: Looking for suggestions of tags that often got low quality questions and would benefit a warning when trying to add that tag

Tags: discussion, tag-warning-request

Per this meta question: [Give moderators the power to add tag warnings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338875/give-moderators-the-power-to-add-tag-warnings) and this one too: [What's the protocol for requesting a tag warning?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298887/whats-the-protocol-for-requesting-a-tag-warning)

There is an option, that needs to be added by Stackexchange admins, to add warnings on the usage of tags.

So what are tags you often see bad/low quality questions on, and what would be the warning message to give?

Comment: Related: [Ability to block/warn about certain combinations of tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15699/4797), [Inconsistency in Minecraft related tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15697/4797)

Comment: These suggested tag warnings should each have their own dedicated discussion, rather than simply having them all as answers here.

Comment: @V2Blast Why do you think that? One answer and comments and votes on it seems to be sufficient to get community consensus to me.

Comment: @pppery: Alternatives to the suggested tag warning can't properly be discussed and voted on in this format; those alternatives could only be suggested as comments, which can only be edited for a limited time and can't be downvoted. Also, each individual answer is not as likely to get attention and feedback from the community in this format; the users who participate in those tags have no way to know from this post's title that a tag relevant to them is being discussed in one of the 8 answers to this post.

Comment: Also, from a practical perspective, having each suggested tag warning just be an answer to this post makes things harder for us, because adding the [status-review] tag to the question just creates a single ticket for us (staff) internally, corresponding to the question post. It's not immediately obvious what needs to be done here, or which requests the community as a whole agrees on. And even if we handled some/all of the current requests, adding the [status-review] tag to this question again would just result in the same problem reoccurring in the future.

Comment: See this relevant Q&A on Meta Stack Exchange: [What's the protocol for requesting a tag warning?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298887/335251) (And the similar Q&A for tag blocks: [How do we request to have a tag blocked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/335251)) It's important to understand when to request a tag warning/block in the first place, before requesting that a tag warning/block be added.

Comment: I'm close voting this as too broad per the above comment exchange.

Answer (score 9):

I'm just going to throw this one out there: [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification)

The warning should replicate the tag info, which provides enough information, but typically is not read by new users:

> Only ask if you have a screenshot, video, or audio clip from the game you want to identify. The only game identification questions allowed on this site are those asking to identify games in movies, pictures, videos, advertisements or otherwise where an unknown game appears - not from a description of what you can recall from memory, or from a picture you drew yourself.

Comment: For me the limit is more 'if you read the question, there is very probably only one game that may fit this description'. Things like trying to identify a game via character names or locations would be off topic by your definition. Even if I do not think there is a question I've ever seen that would be in the gray zone i described.

Comment: @Fredy31 That is not our policy.

Comment: @Fredy31 As Wrigglenite said, the policy for game identification requests is pretty clear to prevent said gray area. In your case, somebody could ask "I'm looking for a game where the MC wears red, is a plumber, and is saving a princess". The answer is obvious, but there are no other details to which game they're looking for. At that point, it's a guessing game

Comment: Created dedicated post for this: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16574/should-we-add-a-tag-warning-to-game-identification

Answer (score 8):

[overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch) should have a tag warning because it can no longer be played, and questions since October 2022 are likely about [overwatch-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-2) instead.

Comment: I don't really see that as needing a tag warning. Such questions should simply be retagged, given that both tags exist – if you start typing `overwatch` into the tag area, both [tag:overwatch] and [tag:overwatch-2] will be suggested. If necessary, the [tag:overwatch] tag's description can simply be edited to remind users that it's only about Overwatch 1.

Comment: Also, something else we've done over on [RPG.SE] with the tag for the 1st edition of an RPG system with multiple editions is to rename the tag from, e.g., `[adnd]` to `[adnd-1e]`. This helps avoid folks mistakenly thinking it's a tag for any edition of the game, rather than a tag for a specific edition. In this case, the mods here could just rename the tag to `overwatch-1` instead.

Comment: That said, there's a discussion here on whether the [tag:overwatch] and [tag:overwatch-2] tags should be merged: [Should we merge the overwatch and overwatch-2 tags?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16550/56295)

Answer (score 7):

[minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands)

> The 'minecraft-commands' tag is not allowed without other tags.
> Questions about Minecraft commands must also specify the Minecraft
> edition. Please add one of these tags: [minecraft-java-edition],
> [minecraft-bedrock-edition].

Quoting [Ability to block/warn about certain combinations of tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15699/4797):

> We already have [blocked
> tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295148/805262) and tag
> warnings, but we need to expand this feature to block or warn about
> certain *combinations* of tags, not just the presence/absence of a
> certain tag.
>
> This argument stems off of the problem where multiple tags are
> necessary, like with [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands). We could have something
> like:
>
> [image: Minecraft Servers Tag Block]
>
> This example was from [this
> argument](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15698/250180).
>
> Here, the tag would be blocked *until* you add one of the other tags
> that are required with it. We could have a combination block on
> [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) unless the question also has
> [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) or [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition). This
> will catch people making the common mistake before it happens, saving
> them from having to wait long periods of time as their question is
> closed and reopened.
>
> We could do this also with combination tag warnings:
>
> [image: If your question pertains to both editions of Minecraft, we'd prefer if you used a seperate question for each edition, unless you're sure the answer would be exactly the same in both editions.]
>
> If implemented, this should be used sparingly, only for commonly
> mistaken tags. It should not be used for obviously wrong things that
> no one would actually do (like blocking the combination
> [keep-talking-and-nobody-explodes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keep-talking-and-nobody-explodes) [papers-please](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papers-please))

Comment: Postscript: [Should we add a tag warning to \[minecraft-commands\]?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16702/should-we-add-a-tag-warning-to-minecraft-commands)

Answer (score 4):

[minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods) / [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods)

> Please note, that we do not allow questions about technical issues for
> Minecraft mods. Feel free to ask questions about *using* mods and
> their in-game functionalities, but be sure to always include enough
> details about the mods in question.

Comment: I would add 'and bugs/interaction between 2 or more mods are off-topic'

Comment: Should probably include the [tag:mods] tag in with this answer IMO. It’s nearly as popular (43 questions this year, vs 59 for its Minecraft counter part).

Comment: @Fredy31 yup, could probably add that too.

Comment: With the addition of the mods tag you *could* remove the reference to Minecraft and make the warning universal for mod tags.

Comment: @Tacoタコス The policy on [not allowing questions about modded Minecraft technical issues covers Minecraft only](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no?noredirect=1&lq=1). Technical issues in other modded games are allowed. The reference to Minecraft should not be removed.

Comment: @galacticninja thanks for the read!

Answer (score 3):

The tag [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues)

Make sure that if you have got an error message or code, google it before asking. If you can't find anything for it, make sure to include them in your question.

Comment: I just stumbled across [a question requesting the same thing from 2014](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8596/185203)

Answer (score 1):

[glitch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glitch)

> The [glitch] tag is for a game that was shut down in 2012. If you are reporting a glitch in a different game then no special tag is needed.

Since we frequently see questions getting that tag when it doesn't belong, and in fact I just edited it off one that was posted several weeks ago.

(Or, for that matter, just blacklist the tag since I don't see it possibly having any new questions)

Comment: Honestly, it seems like that tag should just be renamed to avoid the confusion... (And we don't generally add tag blocks unless the tag has been burninated in the first place, not just for tags that we don't expect new questions on.)

Answer (score 1):

Tags with poor man's tag warnings (screaming in the tag wiki excerpt):

[legal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal)

> Questions asking if something is (il)legal are off topic here.

[xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox)

> This tag is exclusively for questions about the original Xbox, released in 2001. It should not be used for Xbox 360, Xbox One, Xbox Series X/S, or the 'Xbox Games' feature of Windows 10.

[dota](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dota)

> USE THIS TAG FOR QUESTIONS ABOUT DOTA 1 (THE WARCRAFT 3 MAP)

[cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheats)

> We do not allow questions about multiplayer game hacks/exploits that ruin another player's experience for personal gain.

[system-requirements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-requirements)

> This tag is for generalised questions about system requirements not specific to a single PC or laptop.

[google-maps-pokemon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-pokemon)

> DO NOT USE FOR POKEMON GO

[hardware-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-identification)

> These questions are allowed only if you have an actual screenshot, video, etc. of the game hardware you want to identify; not just a description of vague recollections.

(I've excluded things that already have answers above, as well as [completion-time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/completion-time) which I wasn't sure what to do with)

Not necessarily saying all of these warrant tag warnings, and they should probably be rephrased if they do warrant them, but something to think about. This is a community wiki post, so feel free to edit in any better wording suggestions.

Answer (score -6):

Add a 'bait' tag [banned]

I often see questions about banned accounts and well, there is only one thing to answer those: Please contact customer service of the game and plead your case, nothing can be done from your side.

Comment: I'm not sure how a "bait" tag would work for something like this. In order for a tag to exist, there needs to be a question and these types of questions are typically closed/deleted

Comment: I guess if we really go that way we could have a dead question that is left open to have it be in the list. But thats a little 'duct tape'

Comment: The text seems to be too general to be useful to users, and questions about being banned are not as common as the other tag warnings already listed. "nothing can be done from your side" might not even be correct depending on the game.