# Should we merge the overwatch and overwatch-2 tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merging

I understand the motivation for having a different tag for sequels. However, I think Overwatch 2 is an exception, as it's a live service game that completely replaces Overwatch 1 (which cannot be played anymore). As a result, I think it would be appropriate to merge [overwatch-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-2) into [overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch), especially considering that all new Overwatch questions are likely from Overwatch 2 players.

Comment: I do not play Overwatch, so somebody who does might could provide better feedback, but I would almost keep the tags the way they are for historical purposes. While there might be a good bit of overlap between Overwatch and Overwatch 2, not all historical Overwatch questions could be applicable to Overwatch 2

Comment: Can Overwatch 1 owners continue to play OW1 content in OW2? i.e. would it still be possible that a question about OW have a separate answer for OW1 vs OW2 owners?

Comment: @Robotnik No, Overwatch 1 is completely gone. Overwatch 2 is a complete and F2P replacement of OW1. Overwatch 1 players are grandfathered in as having extra heroes, I think, but there is nothing that's exclusive to Overwatch 1 players.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned sooner, but I have played both games. Overwatch 2 has brought on almost all content from Overwatch 1, so it's unlikely that a question would have a different answer in Overwatch 1 and 2. The exceptions would be changes in the meta (which already happened in Overwatch 1) and content promised for future updates. Also if the intent is for the `overwatch` tag to only be about Overwatch 1, we should probably disable adding new questions to it, since nobody can play it.

Comment: Related: [What do we do with questions about games that can no longer be played?](/q/5565/4797), [What should be done with out of version questions?](/q/5727/4797), [What do we do with historic questions that no longer make sense?](/q/7235/4797), [Questions about new game versions](/q/13401/4797), [Dealing with old questions about non-existent features?](/q/14661/4797)

Comment: Overwatch 1 isn't going to be rereleased though. Blizzard has said Overwatch 2 replaces Overwatch completely. Also since it's a multiplayer game, you can't just download it and play it without official servers.

Comment: Are you suggesting we mark new [tag:overwatch] questions as [tag:overwatch-2] instead of merging, or marking as synonyms and then merging?

Answer (score 11):

I believe the tags should stay separate. Despite Overwatch being unavailable in place of Overwatch 2, questions for the original game are still largely unique. Heroes, maps, balance, and more, are very different between games. Going back to all the old questions and updating them to make sense for the new game would be silly, in my opinion. Keep the Overwatch tag as is, maybe with a message that the tag is deprecated with the game being unavailable to play, and make sure that users know to use a new Overwatch-2 tag.

For those asking, here are some questions I consider **unique** to the original Overwatch:

[Why haven't I got the Legendary and Epic skins that come with the Overwatch: Legendary Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/364991/why-havent-i-got-the-legendary-and-epic-skins-that-come-with-the-overwatch-leg) (there are no more lootboxes)

[In what order are lootboxes opened?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/337712/in-what-order-are-lootboxes-opened) (see above)

[Does Orisa's "Halt!" activate when it hits someone?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/336260/does-orisas-halt-activate-when-it-hits-someone) and [What is the range on Orisa's Halt if it hits an object?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310647/what-is-the-range-on-orisas-halt-if-it-hits-an-object) (Orisa no longer has the Halt! ability)

[Does Orisa's Supercharge ultimate stack with other damage buffs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301907/does-orisas-supercharge-ultimate-stack-with-other-damage-buffs) (Orisa no longer has Supercharger as her Ultimate)

[How do I achieve max damage with Doomfist's Seismic Slam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/317649/how-do-i-achieve-max-damage-with-doomfists-seismic-slam) (Doomfist is now a Tank, and no longer has the Seismic Slam ability)

I can go on, but there's 13 pages of Overwatch questions. If someone wants to volunteer to be a janitor and clean up 13 pages of questions with numerous answers, go right ahead, but I do not see any reason to merge the tags. The game is called Overwatch 2. Let's keep the new tag, and leave the old one for legacy purposes. Why knows, with Activision-Blizzard being the money hungry saps they are now, it's only a matter of time until Overwatch Classic comes out, and the questions are relevant again.

Comment: If enough people are interested, this site can come together as a community and weigh in on [introducing a tag warning for the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298890/622284), which would alert question askers attempting to use the tag with a customized message. However, it's worth mentioning that a tag warning is best created when the tag is already being used incorrectly. That does not, yet, appear to be the case, but I figure I would mention this here for the future's sake, in the event that we begin to see it misused.

Comment: That aside, I agree. The games are pretty different, even if OW2 has completely supplanted OW1, and a lot of the old information should stay old and relevantly tagged with only the [overwatch] tag.

Comment: @nightsurfer Can you give an example for "questions for the original game are still largely unique"?

Comment: I still disagree with keeping the tags separate, though I think using a tag warning would be an improvement over not doing anything. I'd argue that [tag:overwatch] would be used incorrectly in this case, since you won't actually be able to use any answers to questions for a game that you can no longer play.

Comment: @Spevacus Tag warnings have never been implemented in Arqade - see: [Tag Warnings: Looking for suggestions of tags that often got low quality questions and would benefit a warning when trying to add that tag](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15994/4797) and all other meta posts tagged [meta-tag:tag-warning-request].

Comment: @NickMcCurdy though you could do this search yourself, I will post an edit to what I consider unique Overwatch 1 questions.

Answer (score 5):

#### The tags should be synonymized: [overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch) → [overwatch-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-2) but *not* merged.

(See the Meta SE post, [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/162827) - for the difference between tag synonyms and merged tags.)

If we do it this way, then questions currently tagged [overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch) and [overwatch-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-2) will stay as they are, with no retagging (no merge). Since some [overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch) questions may not be relevant anymore nor make sense for *Overwatch 2*, we should not merge the tags, and only synonymize them.

After the tags are synonymized, the site will automatically convert/retag all new questions tagged [overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch) to [overwatch-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-2). (No need for tag warnings.)

Using [overwatch-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-2) as the main tag is more appropriate than [overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch), since *Overwatch 1* is obsolete and can't be played anymore, and the tag will reflect the game's current name.

Comment: My concern is that making a minor edit to an [tag:overwatch] question, such as a typo fix, would change it to be a question about [tag:overwatch-2]. As far as I understand, making a tag warning does not have this disadvantage, but has the other advantages of what you and @nightsurfer are suggesting.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy Edits to questions about obsoleted games that can no longer be played are rarely done in Arqade. If they're edited, moderators can easily retag them back. As for tag warnings, they have never been implemented in Arqade - see: [Tag Warnings: Looking for suggestions of tags that often got low quality questions and would benefit a warning when trying to add that tag](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15994/4797).

Comment: Requested a tag warning: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15994/tag-warnings-looking-for-suggestions-of-tags-that-often-got-low-quality-questio/16553#16553

Answer (score 3):

#### No. We should rename [overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch) to [overwatch-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-1) instead.

Advantages:

- [overwatch-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-1) and [overwatch-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-2) questions will stay separate, avoiding the disadvantages that come with merging or synonymizing these two tags, as already mentioned in the other answers and their comments.
- Prevents confusion, since some [overwatch-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-1) questions may not be relevant nor make sense for *Overwatch 2* anymore.
- No need for tag warnings, since the game's iteration is clearly indicated in the tag and tag wiki.
- Since [overwatch-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-2) is not merged to [overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch), [overwatch-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-2) will reflect the game's current iteration's official name.

This idea is from @V2Blast's comment at [Tag Warnings: Looking for suggestions of tags that often got low quality questions and would benefit a warning when trying to add that tag](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15994/tag-warnings-looking-for-suggestions-of-tags-that-often-got-low-quality-questio#comment48806_16553) :

> Also, something else we've done over on [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) with the tag for the 1st edition of an RPG system with multiple editions is to rename the tag from, e.g., [adnd] to [adnd-1e]. This helps avoid folks mistakenly thinking it's a tag for any edition of the game, rather than a tag for a specific edition. In this case, the mods here could just rename the tag to [overwatch-1] instead.

<sup>(Adding another answer because this is a different suggestion to my [initial answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16552/4797). I don't think that I should delete the other answer because it already has a few upvotes.)</sup>

Comment: I suppose a rename would be fine.  But I don't see it really necessary to be honest.