# Should the [counter-strike-global-offensive] tag be merged into [counter-strike-2]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merging

We have two tags right now:

- [counter-strike-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive)
- [counter-strike-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-2)

*Counter Strike 2* is actually the new name/replacement of *Counter Strike: Global Offensive* (i.e. Steam does not have "Counter Strike: Global Offensive" as a game anymore, it has been renamed to "[Counter Strike 2](https://store.steampowered.com/app/730/CounterStrike_2/)" as of September 27th, 2023).

Should we merge the questions tagged as [counter-strike-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive) into [counter-strike-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-2)?

I don't know how much has actually changed between the two "versions" of the game, but CS:GO is no longer officially playable as far as I can tell. I also don't know if older (any?) CS:GO questions can be applied to the "replacement" game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**, I think we shouldn't merge those two tags. Some *CS:GO* questions may not apply or make sense for *CS2* anymore. And according to [Wikipedia’s *CS:GO* article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive) and [Steam Support's
"Legacy CS:GO Version" article](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/73EF-08A3-0935-6369), *CS:GO* players can still access community servers, and a legacy version of *CS:GO* was released later for outdated devices and platforms that cannot run *CS2*. Basically, *CS:GO* will continue to exist independently of *CS2*.

> Official matchmaking for Global Offensive was shut down that day, though players were still able to connect to community servers. A legacy version of Global Offensive was later released for outdated devices and platforms unable to run Counter-Strike 2, though matchmaking was still disabled. Additionally, the game remains playable on Xbox 360.

- [Wikipedia’s *CS:GO* article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive)

> If you are unable to launch Counter-Strike 2 with your current hardware, you can access a legacy version of CS:GO. Support for this version of CS:GO will end on January 1, 2024.

> **What is the legacy version of CS:GO?**
> The legacy version of CS:GO is a frozen build of CS:GO. It has all of the features of CS:GO except for official matchmaking.
>
> **What will happen after the end of support for the legacy version of CS:GO?**
> After January 1, 2024 the game will still be available, but certain functionality that relies on compatibility with the Game Coordinator (e.g., access to inventory) may degrade and/or fail.

- [Steam Support's "Legacy CS:GO Version" article](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/73EF-08A3-0935-6369)

We should add tag usage guidance to both tags’ tag wikis to avoid users using the tag for the wrong game.

Relevant meta discussion posts:

- [What do we do with questions about games that can no longer be played?](/q/5565/4797)
- [What should be done with out of version questions?](/q/5727/4797)
- [What do we do with historic questions that no longer make sense?](/q/7235/4797)
- [Questions about new game versions](/q/13401/4797)
- [Dealing with old questions about non-existent features?](/q/14661/4797)

Comment: Accepted this answer over the others primarily because of all the information 
(plus I didn't know CS:GO is still available to a degree), but the other answers are just as valid.  Either way, seems like the overall answer is **no, leave the tags separate**.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, no. Because they aren't the same game after all, a solution that works (worked) for [counter-strike-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive) probably won't work for [counter-strike-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-2), and vice versa.

Although it doesn't exist anymore, [counter-strike-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive) should exist like a *Legacy Tag*.

Comment: Thanks for the input - come to think of it, I think another game that did a similar thing was Overwatch.  Overwatch became Overwatch 2, with the first game no longer available to play.  And we have tags for both games.

Comment: We actually had a Meta for that too: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16550/should-we-merge-the-overwatch-and-overwatch-2-tags

Answer (score 5):

While I do not play Counter Strike: Global Offensive/Counter Strike 2, I would keep the tags separate - at least for the time being. Per [VideoGamer](https://www.videogamer.com/news/csgo-xbox-360/), Counter Strike: Global Offensive is still available to play on the Xbox 360. By merging the tags, we would lose the ability to ask questions for the Xbox 360 version.

Comment: Didn't actually know it was playable on Xbox 360, let alone _still_ playable on Xbox 360.  I have to imagine that is a very small audience.

Comment: @TimmyJim Those were my thoughts as well. The audience would be incredibly small at best, and I doubt we would ever get questions for it. But still

Comment: The xbox version hasn't been updated since 2013 (it launched in 2012), it was my primary version before I built a pc. It's an interesting little snapshot!

Comment: @GammaGames wow, so basically its an abandoned game nearly on Xbox 360 LOL - but I guess the Xbox One launched in 2013, and Valve probably realized the audience was quite small on Xbox to begin with